# How to insert all images to divs dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have the images:

```
<img src="1.png" alt="" />
<img src="1.png" alt="" />
<img src="1.png" alt="" />
```

And I want to dynamically create (JavaScript):

```
<div><img src="1.png" alt="" /></div>
<div><img src="2.png" alt="" /></div>
<div><img src="3.png" alt="" /></div>
```

Wrap each image within a separate div.

Comment: Duplicate, see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5684842/2126792